# Using name of php variable in function

Tags: php, function

This may seem like a very dumb question, but I don't know if it's possible. I'm trying to write a function as follows:

```
function checkDuplicates($input) {
    $result = pg_query('SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE LOWER(username)=\''.strtolower(pg_escape_string($input)).'\'') or exit(pg_last_error());
}
```

and I want to replace "username" with the name of the variable being passed in. For example, if I called `checkDuplicates($email)`, I want essentially the following function to be called:

```
function checkDuplicates($email) {
    $result = pg_query('SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE LOWER(email)=\''.strtolower(pg_escape_string($email)).'\'') or exit(pg_last_error());
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You probably need something like references

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php

Comment: why not to pass string as a param? 0_o

Comment: If you anyway take the effort to name those variables in your code accordingly, you should rather do it something like `function chkDupe($field, $value) {...}` and `chkDupe('email', $input); chkDupe('name', $imput)` etc

Comment: If you pass an array to the function it can work. Say you have `$input = ['email', 'abc@hotmail.com'];` then you can use [0] as the select and [1] as the search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass the column as a second parameter. Changing your parameter variable name from $input to $email won't actually affect the way in which you call the function.

You can simply do:

```
function checkDuplicates($col, $val, $return_col) {
    $result = pg_query('SELECT '.$return_col.' FROM accounts WHERE LOWER('.$col.')=\''.strtolower(pg_escape_string($val)).'\'') or exit(pg_last_error());
}
```

Keep the usual SQL injection dangers in the back of your mind when you're doing this. You may want to run the `$col` and `$return_col` input through a whitelist, etc.

Comment: Can you tell me about SQL injection/point me to some helpful links?

Comment: @Prangle See the first **Related** question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: @Prangle The concept of SQL injection is pretty simple. Barmar's link can help you out, but you can also look it up on Google. It's such a simple/common concept that there's no need to give you any specific links. The basic idea is that the variable values you put into your query are interpreted literally when sent to the database as SQL, and problems can arise. Imagine if `$return_col` in the query above had a value of `1; UPDATE accounts SET password='123456'`. Injections don't have to be malicious either - simple typos or chars can cause unexpected bugs and stuff too.